# Nodemon can't find module imports in same directory?

Tags: node.js, typescript, nodemon

I have a very basic index.js that has these imports like so:

```
import { MikroORM } from "@mikro-orm/core";
import { __prod__ } from "./constants";
import { Post } from "./entities/Post";
```

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "reddit-server",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "watch": "tsc -w",
    "dev": "nodemon dist/index.js",
    "start": "node dist/index.js",
    "start2": "ts-node src/index.ts",
    "dev2": "nodemon --exec ts-node src/index.ts",
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "keywords": [],
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^16.3.2",
    "nodemon": "^2.0.12",
    "ts-node": "^10.1.0",
    "typescript": "^4.3.5"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mikro-orm/cli": "^4.5.7",
    "@mikro-orm/core": "^4.5.7",
    "@mikro-orm/migrations": "^4.5.7",
    "@mikro-orm/postgresql": "^4.5.7",
    "pg": "^8.6.0"
  }
}
```

I compile them with tsc into a dist directory with structure like:
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/uC5pU.png

It gives me the error:

```
Cannot find module '/Users/kevinli/reddit-clone/reddit-server/dist/constants' imported from /Users/kevinli/reddit-clone/reddit-server/dist/index.js
```

I'm confused because they seem to be in the same directory and should be importing correctly?

If I try to remove `"type": "module",`, it tells me I cannot import something outside a module.

Comment: You need to add this `"type": "module"` to tell the node to use ES6 imports. What is the error you are getting while adding this config? How are you exporting things from constant module?

Comment: Can you show the contents of your tsconfig.json file?

Comment: Another hint, when using ES6 modules in node, is to rename all js-files to "mjs" to make a distinction. Then specify the extension both in imports and in package.json's scripts and main. For me, was necessary last time I enabled ES6 modules (using node v14.15.3)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I faced the same issue today.

Try adding the extension `.js` or whatever it is to the import path.
I learnt without the extension nodejs assumes the path is a directory, so it will be expecting an `index.js` (default) file inside it.

Comment: Weird thing is my files are written in TypeScript, but the imports are declared as if I was importing a JS file...